# Toolbar in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to study how to develop a toolbar using Javascript
Can anyone please post some useful links to develop a toolbar.
If any one have sample code, please share it.

Comment: a toolbar, or a browser addon?

Comment: i want a toolbar which i need to add links to facebook, twitter etc

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery UI:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#toolbar